# Django | Auto Escape On / Off | Single Quotes | JSON

Tags: python, django, django-templates, escaping

I have address field in a form. I'm sending that form to web server after converting it to json. Unexpectedly when a user enters the text `'X' Road` in the address field, it is escaping using `\`. I saved that info in database and then sending back to client.

`jresp = '{% autoescape on%}{{jresp}}{% endautoescape %}';`

But unfortunately here escape characters are not presented. The tag is closing when encountering the text `'X Road'`

Here is the snippet...

```
jresp = 
'{"data":  
    {"alt_mobile": "7396623933", "father": "Janaiah", "gender": true, "surname": "Boddu", 
     "mobile": "9010101046", "religion": "Hindu", "mother": "Parvathi", 
     "address": "Khammam 'X' Road, Road No: 5", "dob": "14 July, 1995", 
     "cast": "Bc - B", "lastname": "Sai ", "temp_address": "Hyderabad", 
     "firstname": "Gowtham", "mother_maiden_name": "Mothukuri"}, 
     "rollno": "12261A0109", "academics": 
                                     {"mtech_pref": 2, "abckl_total": 0, 
                                      "aieeerank": 44978, "engg_t_agg": 69.32, 
                                      "job_pref": 1, "sem4_total": 750, "sem1_pbckl": 0, 
                                      "verify": false, "sem7_pbckl": 0, 
                                      "x2class_year_of_pass": 2012, "sem2_abckl": 0, 
                                      "x2class_board": "BIEAP", "sem8_marks": 0, 
                                      "xclass_total": 700, "sem3_total": 750,  
                                      "x2class_t_agg": 89.8, "ms_pref": 3, "sem5_abckl": null,  
                                      "sem4_marks": 515, "x2class_total": 1000, "sem2_marks": 545,  
                                      "sem6_pbckl": 0, "sem3_pbckl": 0, "evaluation_test": false,  
                                      "sem5_pbckl": null, "pbckl_history": true, "sem6_total": 0,  
                                      "is_icse": false, "is_inter": true,  
                                      "abckl_history": false, "sem8_pbckl": 0, "comp_xclass_t_agg": 3,  
                                      "is_ssc": false, "sem1_total": 1000, "x2class_name": "CVR",  
                                      "x2class_marks": 898, "branch": 1, "sem6_abckl": 0,  
                                      "xclass_t_agg": 89.71, "sem1_abckl": 0, "pbckl_total": 0,  
                                      "xclass_name": "SVVN", "sem8_total": 0, "xclass_marks": 628,  
                                      "sem4_abckl": 0, "sem2_pbckl": 0, "mba_pref": 4,  
                                      "sem7_marks": 0, "sem6_marks": 0, "xclass_year_of_pass": 2010,  
                                      "sem7_abckl": 0, "sem2_total": 750, "sem7_total": 0,  
                                      "comp_x2class_t_agg": 3, "sem4_pbckl": 0,  
                                      "comp_engg_t_agg": 2, "sem1_marks": 693, "is_isce": null,  
                                      "sem3_marks": 500, "sem3_abckl": 0, "sem5_marks": null,  
                                      "xclass_board": "SSC", "task_reg": false, "cetrank": 23592,  
                                      "sem8_abckl": 0, "sem5_total": null}}';
```

It is not supposed to raise the error, but I get an error in the console!

[image]

**Questions:**

How to resolve the issue?

What exactly is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `autoescape` tag escapes special HTML characters (`<` and `>`), not single quotes.

If you want to escape single quotes, you can write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters).

For example:

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def escape_single_quotes(string):
    # The two backslashes are interpreted as a single one
    # because the backslash is the escaping character.
    return string.replace("'", "\\'")
```

If you do not wish to use a template filter, what you can do is this:

```
{# Note the type is not "text/javascript" so the browser does not try to interpret the content. #}
<script id="jresp" type="application/json">{{ jresp }}</script>
<script>
  var jsresp = document.getElementById('jsreps').innerHTML;
</script>
```

This second solution is better practice because you are not rendering the JS with Django which means it can be moved to an external file.

Comment: Is there any solution that we can implement in Javascript? It is not that I am not happy with your solution. I'm just curious to know possible implementations in Client Side...!

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for sharing.